# What type is RMI?

Tags: java

Does RMI belong to the object oriented middle ware type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With all the cautions related the use of words, as already explained before, RMI can certainly be considered an object oriented middleware. It allows you to return object by value (serializing them) or by reference (offering you a reference to invoke methods on the remote object).

In the old days (back to 1996) were considered OO middleware also Voyager ( http://www.springerlink.com/content/cn20847n36378048/ ) and HORB ( http://www.springerlink.com/content/c1156178g025x422/ ). I can probably say that the "reference" OO middleware is/was anyway CORBA ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CORBA )

All those were commonly categorized as "ORB", that stands for Object Request Broker ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_request_broker )

Answer (score 4):

"Middleware" is another of these vague marketing terms that means whatever somone trying to make a sale wants them to mean.

But I'd say while RMI is certainly object-oriented, it does not qualify as middleware, because it offers no functionality of its own. It's a communications protocol and API.

Of course, there is a lot of middleware *using* RMI.

Comment: I think that RMI implementation is a middleware because it is a software component, right? It does something to let different parts of the system get connected... Vague.

Comment: @Vlad: by that definition, TCP/IP is middleware as well, as is Ethernet.

Comment: @Michael: Sure, so RMI qualifies as middleware, isn't it?

Comment: @Vlad: no. None of these qualifies as middleware by any reasonable definition. Of course, that won't prevent any sales droid from using it that way.

Comment: @Michael: I'd say that according to Wiki (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middleware) everything qualifies as middleware, basically. I mean, even `printf` function is a middleware, as it connects a program with a human trough a stream of characters that he or she can understand. Whatever... Marketing... :)

Comment: then why define middleware in the first place. Useless term.

Comment: @user602774: There's quite a number of such useless buzzwords. The main benefit seems to be to managers and salespeople who use them to bamboozle other managers and potential buyers.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... Java RMI can be used to implement OO-style middleware systems, so I guess that's a 'yes'?

You can read more about RMI from [Oracle's RMI Home](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-136424.html) or from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_remote_method_invocation).

Answer (score 0):

RMI is a Java technology, and it is a software component. It does connect different parts of applications (and processes) together. Java is object oriented. So you definitely can combine all those definitions and say that RMI belongs to the object oriented middleware.